# Problem in selecting mesh in 2.7 version of blender

Tags: customization

So I was doing a tutorial that requires 2.79 version but the problem is when you left click the 3d cursor moves so how can we change the key to select a mesh.

Answer (score 0):

File > User Preferences > Input > Select With > Left or Right

[image]

Comment: Thanks bro. You saved my day!